# Syntax colouring using Swing

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to have something like a `JTextArea` which will color some keywords based on some mappings I have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, because I believe `JTextArea` only directly supports a single font in a single color.

According to [`SyntaxHighlighter` class](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/Teaching/Resources/COMS30122/tools/highlight/design.html) article, `JTextPane` is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few other choices that you could try

1. http://ostermiller.org/syntax/editor.html
2. http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/text/editor_kit/index.html
3. http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/
4. http://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/